# The letter 'p' doesn't work in my lock screen, even using On Screen Keyboard

Tags: windows, login, keyboard

The letter 'p' doesn't work on my lock screen, even using On-Screen Keyboard. Finally, I tried [Alt]+112 to type p and it worked. Then I find that 'p' doesn't work only in Windows 10 login and after login, it works. Any clues on what has happened?

BTW I was away and there are some guests at home who have tried logging in by entering random passwords.

Comment: I think some of your guests manage to get in and do stuff.

Comment: No, they didn't. I was able to view the screen with a CCTV cam. But I'm unsure of any key combinations they used and they have no clue what they did.

Comment: If you have alternate keyboard layouts, e.g., English and Norwegian, switch to the one used to enter the password.

Comment: Interestingly I'm facing the exact same issue with the exact same key. I am the only one with access to this computer, and I tried with both English and Japanese input. Neither works. I thought it was a broken keyboard, and I went and ordered a new one.